# Melhor formatação de arquivos xhtml

Tags: eclipse, xhtml

Dado o trecho do meu arquivo `.xhtml`:

```
<h:panelGrid id="camposPesquisa" columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['nome']}: " />
    <p:inputText value="#{naturemb.arg}" />
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid id="botoes" columns="2" styleClass="botoesCrud">
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{naturemb.pesquisar}"
        value="#{msg['pesquisar']}" ajax="false"
        update="cadastro,pesquisa" />
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{naturemb.novo}"
        value="#{msg['novo']}" ajax="false" update="cadastro"
        styleClass="separadorBotoes" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Observem que ao indentar pelo **Eclipse**, há muitas quebras de linhas nos atributos. Tem como configurar para que não quebre tanto de linha?

Ex: 5 atributos na mesma linha, etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim existem opções para isso.

1 - Primeiro verifique se a identação está quebrando cada atributo por linha em:

```
Window>Preferences>Web>HTML files>Editor
```

Desmarque a opção split multiples attributes ...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Aumente o tamanho de caracteres por linha mude o número de `line width` que está 100 (na imagem) para um valor adequado para sua necessiada.

Comment: Show, obrigado.